# My custom block doesn't show up in the block library

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-blocks

I am developing a custom module in Drupal 8. It shows data regarding some organizations that make use of our service. For this I have created a Controller that shows data from the database, which is put there by another module. From the scarce information and tutorials available on Drupal 8 developement I've been able to create the following. In the .routing.yml file I have created a path to this overview table like so (it doesn't properly copy here but the indents are okay):

```
   OrganizationOverview.world:
     path: '/world'
     defaults:
       _controller:      'Drupal\OrganizationOverview\Controller\OrganizationOverviewController::overview'
    _title: 'World'
  requirements:
    _role: 'administrator'
    _permission: 'access content'
```

So now the overview is accessible with the URL `site.com/world`. But what we want is to show it on the frontpage or show it anywhere else on the site. For this it needs to be a Block. For this I have created an `OrganizationOverviewBlock` class in `OrganizationOverview/src/Plugin/Block/OrganizationOverviewBlock.php` which is the proper way according to the PSR-4 standard. The class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\OrganizationOverview\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

/**
 * Provides a 'OrganizationOverviewBlock' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *  id = "organization_overview_block",
 *  admin_label = @Translation("OrganizationOverviewBlock"),
 *  category = @Translation("Custom")
 * )
 */
class OrganizationOverviewBlock extends BlockBase 
{


    public function build()
    {
        return array(
            '#markup' => 'Hello World',
        );
    }

    public function blockAccess(AccountInterface $account)
    {
        return $account->hasPermission('access content');
    }

}
```

So now it should show up in the Blocks Layout page (after flushing cache, which I do consistently) at `site.com/admin/structure/block/` as "Organization Overview Block" where I should enable it, according to plenty sources ([Create custom Block](https://www.drupal.org/node/2101565), [Block API Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/block_api)). But it doesn't show up there. I've tried implementing ContainerFactoryPluginInterface with some of those methods but that changes nothing. It does not show up. I've tried making a new test module with a block with the same code but a simpler name and it does not show up. I've copied the code to another platform (the production site) but it also doesn't show up there. What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me? I know Drupal 8 is new but this module really needs to be published soon.

Comment: I'm voting for this question to be closed on StackOverflow, and moved to [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com). I think you will have a better chance on a helpful answer there.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37856161/1153703

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll find a working example of building custom block in the Drupal  Examples Project. So:

- Get the [Drupal 8 examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples)  project
- Enable the Block Example Module
- Double check the working code

With that, you should get your block available in your own module

You can also take advantage  of what explained [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2101565), where a single php file do the all job. Check files and folders path also.

Answer (score 1):

Not require routing file for custom block.

```
<pre>
class TestBlock extends BlockBase {

/*
** {@inheritdoc}
*/

public function build() {
   return array(
     '#markup' => $this->t('Welcome page!'),
   );
   }
}
</pre>
```

http://drupalasia.com/article/drupal-8-how-create-custom-block-programatically

Answer (score 1):

You should respect the Drupal coding standard recommendations:
No camelCase naming convention in module name.

OrganizationOverview actually is an error, you should use organization_overview (lowercase/underscore) naming conventions.